# Combine CSV files with missing IDs

Tags: python, file, csv

I have 2 CSV files - `output.csv` and `result.csv`.

**output.csv**

```
id, data1, data2, data3
56, 78, 38, 223
67, 12, 35, 52
1, 7, 100, 500
```

**result.csv**

```
id, data4, data5, data6
56, at, text, 78
1, random, text, 23
```

I wish to write a function to create a new CSV file which contains data from both files. Some files have missing ID's and these should be included in the file. For example, from the above files:

**combinedFiles.csv**

```
id, data1, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6
56, 78, 38, 223, at, text, 78
67, 12, 35, 52,,,
1, 7, 100, 500, random, text, 23
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a dictionary from the second file utilize as a lookup for the first:

```
import csv
[h1, *d1], [h2, *d2] = list(csv.reader(open('output.csv'))), list(csv.reader(open('result.csv')))
_d1, _d2 = {a:b for a, *b in d1}, {a:b for a, *b in d2}
with open('combinedFiles.csv', 'w') as f:
  write = csv.writer(f)
  write.writerows([[*h1, *h2[1:]], *[[a, *(b+_d2.get(a, []))] for a, b in _d1.items()]])
```

Output:

```
id,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6
56,78,38,223,at,text,78
67,12,35,52,,,
1,7,100,500,random,text,23
```